# How to resolve the issue regarding Tensorflow and cuda compatibility?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

**Error :**

> UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably
>   because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning
>   log message was printed above. [Op:Conv2D]

**command used for package installation :**

```
conda install -c anaconda keras-gpu
```

**Installed :**

- tensorflow 2.0.0
- cudatoolkit 10.0.130 0
- cudnn 7.6.5
- cuda10.0_0
- keras-gpu 2.2.4 0

  `tf.test.is_gpu_available()`
  returns `True`

Comment: You can try installing `tensorflow-gpu` instead of `keras-gpu`

Answer (score 0):

> UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably
>   because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning
>   log message was printed above. [Op:Conv2D]

Generally this problem appears due to incompatibility between CUDA and cuDNN drivers installed. Please refer tested build configuration for [Linux](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) an [CPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

If `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` returns `True` means, there is nothing wrong with  installation.

So in the next step, you can try GPU memory resources management by allowing GPU memory growth.

It can be done by calling `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth`, which attempts to allocate only as much GPU memory as needed for the runtime allocations: it starts out allocating very little memory, and as the program gets run and more GPU memory is needed, we extend the GPU memory region allocated to the TensorFlow process.

To turn on memory growth for a specific GPU, use the following code prior to allocating any tensors or executing any ops.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

Another method to enable memory growth is to set the environmental variable `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH` to `true`. This configuration is platform specific.

In this method to configure a virtual GPU device with `tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration` and set a hard limit on the total memory to allocate on the GPU.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

For more details please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth)

One suggestion here, you can try installing `tensorflow-gpu` instead of `keras-gpu`.