# How to fix cuDNN initialization error while training a CNN model in tensorflow?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

When I run a basic CNN model for Mnist data set it throws me this error, I have installed the necessary gpu support for linux from , https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu , I am running pop os and when I check for available gpus it is available however this error is thrown how do I fix it!? I have checked the other forums having this issue and they had asked me to reinstall the cudnn drivers which I did!!

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 28, 28, 1)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 13, 13, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 6, 6, 64)          18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 2, 128)         73856     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                5130      
=================================================================
Total params: 360,458
Trainable params: 360,458
Non-trainable params: 


Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node model/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-16-82b08831ea37>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_813]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: Make sure you only have one instance of python running that is using tensorflow

Comment: @Pinkman8144, Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you refer solution discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62110228/14290681) may solve your issue. Thanks!